# count the same number , if appears more than once, as one occurence only

Tags: c#

So i am new to c sharp and been playing around with my code but could not figure it out.
Let say i have the following:

```
Code : 2 1 1 1 1 2
Guess: 2 2 1 2 2 1
```

Firstly, ignore the spots where the guess matches the code. After that, only

> 2 2 2 1

will be left for the guess and

> 1 1 1 2

for the code

If you see for the rest of the code, there is three 2's for the guess but only one in the code. I want to count the three 2's as only one occurrence but the part of my code accounts for all 3 which i cant seem to get it working to count as one.

Here is my code. I only post the part im having trouble on.

```
if (guess.Contains(Code[i]))
{
       if (guess.Distinct().Count() > 1)
       diffSpot++;
}
```

I tried using distinct to get only unique numbers only and count to see that if its greater than 1 , it means there is dupe (same occurence in a row) but i guess im missing something. Thanks for any helpful hints and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liang,

Assuming that what you're after is this:

[image]

I kind of like LINQ for this:

```
using System.Linq;
int[] Code = {2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2};
int[] Guess = {2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1};
int total =
     Guess.Select((g, i) => new {g, i})
    .Where(x => x.g != Code[x.i])
    .Select(x => x.g).Distinct().Count();
```

Returns 2.
Hope this helps.

Comment: i actually got around a solution but this is  interesting!